# Get, Set, nothing is returned with greater than operator

Tags: c#

I'm just testing something out, and it seems it doesn't work as intended. I cannot see clearly why this wouldn't work.

Look now, added the whole program that should work??:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AgeGroup a = new AgeGroup();

        Console.Write("Write your age: ");
        a.AgeTest1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class AgeGroup
{
    private int age;

    public int AgeTest1
    {
        get { return this.age; }
        set
        {
            if (this.age > 65) 
                Console.WriteLine("Nope not working!");
            this.age = value;
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you setting your properties? Note that the way your setters are written, the condition will only trigger with a "lag of 1". i.e. `AgeTest1 = 100; AgeTest1 = 1;` will print the warning only with the second assignment

Comment: The code works fine for me as written. I think this has more to do with what you *expect* it to do. Please describe the steps you're taking, what results you expect, and what results you're getting.

Comment: Did you want to make a check on the input `value`?

Comment: These are not running at the same time, I just put these like this so you guys could see.

Comment: Okey, I'm sorry. My expected result is just what shows in the code. If the age is over 65 then the person is not working. That's all. And this is no code at all and should work. But the result in console is nothing.

Comment: You're expecting to be able to check the value of `this.age` before you assign to it?!?  Why do you expect that?

Comment: As @knittl explains, what you are doing is checking if the last person to have been set is over 65 before you remember the current person's age.  You may also want to re-phrase your "Nope, not Working!" to something referencing retirement.  I read your code and assumed that "not working" meant that there was a problem in the logic (i.e, the logic is not working) if the previous value of age was >65.  And, oh, by the way, some of us are old and do work :-)

Comment: Hey, haha. I know many of you youngsters are working still. ;) But what I don't understand is, if I change the greater than to a less than operator, it works. Am I not thinking clearly?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` does not set our expectations for what input you provide unless you also tell us what you typed.

Comment: The initial value of `this.age` is 0.  Then you check to see if it's greater than 65 (it's not).  Then you assign it the value of whatever you typed in the console.  (Who knows??)  Presumably you typed something > 65.  Maybe you typed 65?  We'll never know unless you describe your expectations and describe your input.

Comment: What I typed? The code  says: Write your age, and if it is over 65 then the person is retired. Btw, I typed 70.

Comment: You're going to facepalm when you eventually are able to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Yepp.... I just found out. Dammit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the current value of the backing field, not the value being assigned to the property. I assume that you meant:

```cs
public int AgeTest1
{
    get { return this.age; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 65)
            Console.WriteLine("Nope not working!");
        this.age = value;
    }
}
```

or

```cs
public int AgeTest1
{
    get { return this.age; }
    set
    {
        this.age = value;
        if (this.age > 65)
            Console.WriteLine("Nope not working!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Wyck I agree that it is propably "it".